# paypal integration for payment

Tags: php, html, paypal

My email is shown in header of Paypal. [image: paypal website with my email in header]

Please help me solve this. I want my website name there. Are there any HTML hidden fields which controls this part of the website?

It would be better if I can manage my website logo there in header. And, website name in the section of

> PayPal securely processes payments for XXXXXXXX@gmail.com

The values I have passed to Paypal website are:

```
$myPaypal = new Paypal();
$myPaypal->addField('business', 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com');
$myPaypal->addField('currency_code', 'USD');
$myPaypal->addField('return', SITE_PATH.'cards/index.php?show_card');
$myPaypal->addField('cancel_return', SITE_PATH.'cards/index.php?error_payment');
$myPaypal->addField('notify_url', SITE_PATH.'cards/payment_gates/paypal_ipn.php');
$myPaypal->addField('item_name', $item_name);
$myPaypal->addField('amount', $cost);
$myPaypal->addField('item_number', $order_id);
$myPaypal->addField('custom', $item_name);
$myPaypal->submitPayment();
```

What field should be added to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myPaypal->addField('image_url', 'www.yoursitename.com/img/logo.jpg');
```

Comment: But, it gives the image only on the header part, 
can you see in the image above again pls, PayPal securely processes payments for xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com.

Email is displayed in two places. is there anyway to put my business name there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the PHP bindings, but if this is the Express Checkout API you are using the API parameter you need to send is `PAGESTYLE` with the value set to the name of the customized page style you set up in your merchant account.

Paypal docs have more info: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing

Comment: I am asking if we have any input field that carries this value?

Comment: Check out the `BRANDNAME` parameter. https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

Answer (score 0):

Use your PayPal mail
https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/mytools/apiaccess/firstparty/cert

if you don't have one create one here:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-list-auths

it's look something like this: **yn_api1.example.com**